# TypeError: > not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, loops

```
scores = input("Input a list of student scores\n ").split()
for n in range(0, len(scores)):
  scores[n] = int(scores[n])
print(scores)

# for loop way
highest=0
for s in scores:
   if s > highest:
        highest=scores
print(f"the highest score is {highest}")
```

```
please help me how to solve it? I searched it they are saying to add [0] after s example :
```

for s in scores:
if s[0] > highest:

```
but it did not work and I had the same error
```

please help me
tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

Comment: `highest=s` not `highest=scores`

Comment: Welcome to SO! It sounds like you are feeling a bit impatient waiting for an answer. You may find it useful to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
highest=scores
```

You are assigning a `list` (`scores`) to an `int` var (`highest`), and this is the reason for the error.

I think you have to change the line in

```
highest=s
```